# Is there a way to stop three.js from assigning a width and height to its dom element?

Tags: three.js

I need to place my `three.js` canvas in the dom with a very specific CSS, but `three.js` is overriding its style by setting a pixel-based `width` and `height` every time the renderer is resized.

I override it back to what I want afterwards, but it usually ends up being visibly glitchy for one frame due to that.

Is there any way to make `three.js` *not* decide the style of the dom element for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WebGLRenderer.setSize](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setSize) has an optional parameter `updateStyle` which expects a boolean.

When false, it prevents three.js canvas from updating DOM element style. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dypoq394/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Pass "false" as the 3rd parameter to renderer.setSize().